# C# unique index generic collection

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I need a collection that exposes [] operator, contains only unique objects, and are generic. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) represents a collection of keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

[`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Comment: Hashset<T> does not expose [], it is not ordered

Comment: @jamietre, `[]` is an indexer access. It has nothing to do with ordering.

Comment: OK then, HashSet does not not expose indexer access. Specifically because it is meaningless in an unordered data structure.

Comment: OK I just understood our confusion. I assumed he was looking for access by *ordinal* index. That is actually not clear (or not specified anyway) from his question. But still hashsets don't have any [] operator, they have `Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "exposes the [] operator."

If you want to be able to access objects in a unique collection by some arbitrary key, then use a `Dictionary<string key, object value>`.

If you want to be able to create a list of unique objects which permits access by an ordinal index, in the order in which objects were added, you will need to roll something of your own. I am not aware of any framework class that offers both uniqueness like a `HashSet<T>` and also allows access to objects in the order in which they were added, like a `List<T>`. `SortedSet<T>` almost does it, but does not have indexer access - so while it does maintain order, it does not allow access using that order except through enumeration. You could use Linq extension method `ElementAt` to access the element at a particular ordinal index, but performance would be very bad since this method works by iteration.

You could use also `Dictionary<int key, object value>` but you will still have to maintain the index yourself, and if anything is ever removed, you'd have a hole in your list. This would be a good solution if you never had to remove elements.

To have both uniqueness and access by index, and also be able to remove elements, you need a combination of a hash table and an ordered list. I created such a class recently. I don't think this is necessarily the most efficient implementation since it does its work by keeping two copies of the lists (one as a `List<T>` and one as a `HashSet<T>`).

In my situation, I valued speed over storage efficiency, since the amount of data wasn't large. This class offers the speed of a `List<T>` for indexed access and the speed of a `HashTable<T>` for element access (e.g. ensuring uniqueness when adding) at the expense of twice the storage requirements.

An alternative would be to use just a `List<T>` as your basis, and verify uniqueness before any add/insert operation. This would be more memory efficient, but much slower for add/insert operations because it doesn't take advantage of a hash table.

Here's the class I used.

http://snipt.org/xlRl

Answer (score 0):

The HashSet class should do the trick.  See [HashSet(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) for more information.  If you need them to maintain a sorted order, the SortedSet should do the trick.  See [SortedSet(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) for more information about that class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to store unique objects (entities, for example) while exposing a [], then you want to use the KeyedCollection class.

[MSDN KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

// This class represents a very simple keyed list of OrderItems,
// inheriting most of its behavior from the KeyedCollection and 
// Collection classes. The immediate base class is the constructed
// type KeyedCollection<int, OrderItem>. When you inherit
// from KeyedCollection, the second generic type argument is the 
// type that you want to store in the collection -- in this case
// OrderItem. The first type argument is the type that you want
// to use as a key. Its values must be calculated from OrderItem; 
// in this case it is the int field PartNumber, so SimpleOrder
// inherits KeyedCollection<int, OrderItem>.
//
public class SimpleOrder : KeyedCollection<int, OrderItem>
{
    // The parameterless constructor of the base class creates a 
    // KeyedCollection with an internal dictionary. For this code 
    // example, no other constructors are exposed.
    //
    public SimpleOrder() : base() {}

    // This is the only method that absolutely must be overridden,
    // because without it the KeyedCollection cannot extract the
    // keys from the items. The input parameter type is the 
    // second generic type argument, in this case OrderItem, and 
    // the return value type is the first generic type argument,
    // in this case int.
    //
    protected override int GetKeyForItem(OrderItem item)
    {
        // In this example, the key is the part number.
        return item.PartNumber;
    }
}
```